# What to do with a DNA sequencer?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, dna, dna-sequencing

My school is very fortunate to have a DNA sequencer, and I want to find an opportunity to learn how to use it. I'm currently taking AP Biology this year, and I hope to do an independent study in biology next year, concerning DNA. I'm sure there's plenty I can do with the sequencer, but do you have any cool project ideas?

Comment: You might want to narrow that down a little. What kind of equipment do you have access to (apart from the sequencer)? How much time would you have for this project? Do you plan to do this alone or will there be a teacher to help?

Comment: Agree with @terdon, but you'll have to do a bit of scouting out of possible options (based on time limitations and supplies), and then maybe this will have a concrete answer based on those.  This is not to discourage you, just to get you a better answer.  IOW, Way to take the initiative so early in your education!

Comment: Also, will there be some money available for the project, and if so how much? That may be a limiting factor for certain experiments.

Comment: You can [edit] this post to respond to the feedback in the above commments

Comment: @Jack What we once did with a sequencer was to isolate bacteria from our rooms and take their dna out and sequence it and then compare the sequences using BLAST and RDP and construct a phylogenetic tree using that. But I think this is a really basic project with no importance except to learn the basic techniques which you can apply elsewhere.

Comment: @Jack I had also read an experiment where they isolated microbes from different soils and identified different microbes using PCR and sequencing and then tried to identify which are the most necessary.

Comment: Then there was one more experiment in which gut microbes from different people were isolated and it was found that different types of bacteria were present based on whether people were primarily veg. or non veg.

Comment: Deciding on your project will also depend on whether you want to use your sequencing machine as a main tool or as a supplement to your project and one more thing - all examples I gave u r regarding microbes but there are gazillion other organisms on which you could try sequencing....This was just to give u a start.